# Why aren't both subplots showing tick marks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to plot some data via a scatter graph, and I would expect matplotlib to automatically add tick marks, which it does do on the first subplot. However, the second subplot does not have ticks with labels added automatically. I have tried setting the ticks myself explicitly which didn't work (using xticks and xticklabels).

Below is my code:

```
axs[0].scatter(dates, yvar, color="black", label="Data")
axs[0].plot(dates, predictions, color="blue", label="Predicted Value")
axs[1].scatter(predictions, yvar, color="red", label="Prediction vs Data")
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
fig.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you could remove the strange looking calls to `plt.xticks(())` and `plt.yticks(())`? How is the exact command that created the `axs`? Could you add an image of your plot? Could you add some test data?  Did you try to call `plt.tight_layout()` at the end to fit the labels nicely into the plot?

Comment: Huh, removing the plt.xticks and plt.yticks worked, but I would like to know why as most of this code was cribbed from a tutorial on linear regression plotting.

Comment: No tutorial should include `(())`.  Also, the tutorial should avoid mixing the object-oriented interface with the old-style pyplot interface.

Answer (score 1):

This code, trying to replicate your problem, behaves as expected. It produces the `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`:

Try to call your legend with each `ax` individually

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 360, 1)
y = np.sin(2 * x * np.pi / 180)
z = np.cos(2 * x * np.pi / 180)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].scatter(x, y, label='label1')
ax[0].plot(x, z, label='label2')
ax[1].scatter(y, z, label='label3')
ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]